# Issue with Angular scrollable and flex directive in scroll container

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-directive

I am facing an issue when trying to use the Angular `scrollable` directive in a container with the `flex` property. The directive doesn't seem to activate when I add flex styles to the container, and when I remove those styles, the scroll behavior is not as expected.

I am using the `scrollable` directive to detect scroll events in a container that has the `overflow-y: auto` property. The structure is something like this

```
<div class="flex overflow-y-auto flex-col-reverse h-full scrollable-container" scrollable (scrollPosition)="scrollHandler($event)">
  <!-- Contet here-->
</div>
```

The issue is that when I add the flex class, the directive doesn't seem to activate correctly, and when I remove it, the scroll behaves unexpectedly, i.e., the scroll position starts at the top.

What I'm trying to achieve is infinite scrolling in Angular to load paginated data. However, I can't get the directive to work correctly; I want to be able to capture the 'top' event when the user scrolls up to load more data. I should mention that I'm using Angular Firestore, but my issue is with the styles. This is the tutorial I was trying to follow: [Link](https://fireship.io/lessons/infinite-scroll-firestore-angular/)
My application is a chat, so the cursor must be at the bottom and when the user scrolls to the top I must load more data

The directive I'm using

```
import { Directive, HostListener, EventEmitter, Output, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[scrollable]'
})
export class ScrollableDirective {

  @Output() scrollPosition = new EventEmitter()
  
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener('scroll', ['$event'])
  onScroll(event) {
    try {

      const top = event.target.scrollTop
      const height = this.el.nativeElement.scrollHeight
      const offset = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight

      // emit bottom event
      if (top > height - offset - 1) {
        this.scrollPosition.emit('bottom')
      }

      // emit top event
      if (top === 0) {
        this.scrollPosition.emit('top')
      }

    } catch (err) {}
  }

}
```

Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to address this situation? I would appreciate any help or guidance. Thank you